# Plotly traces not visible after updating menu

Tags: python, plotly

I'm plotting scattergeo plots on a US map (51 traces for 51 states including DC and 4 traces for 4 different years). I have updatemenus with 2 buttons that switch between one scattergeo with legend (51 traces) and another scattergeo with a slider at the bottom (4 traces). I initially set the 4 traces (years) `visible = False` because I wanted only the 51 traces to appear initially but when I click the button to switch to scattergeo with slider and set first 51 traces `visible = False` and final 4 traces `visible = [True, False, False, False]` none of my traces are visible on the map.

No sure why this is happening. When I set `cities_year` `visible = True` when first creating the scattergeo (i.e. they are visible initially) the traces appear but I don't want that because then I have the all my scatterpoints being plotted twice on top of each other.

Here is some code to create dataset:

```
data = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/2014_us_cities.csv')
data = data.iloc[:400] # Keep only first 400 samples
data.loc[:100, 'year'] = '1990'
data.loc[100:200, 'year'] = '1991'
data.loc[200:300, 'year'] = '1992'
data.loc[300:, 'year'] = '1993'
```

I am using plotly version 2.7.0 and the offline plotting
Here is my plotly code:

```
cities = []
for state in data['name'].value_counts().index:
    data_sub = data.loc[data['name'] == state]
    city = dict(
        type = 'scattergeo',
        visible = True,
        locationmode = 'USA-states',
        lon = data_sub['lon'],
        lat = data_sub['lat'],
        mode = 'markers',
        marker = dict(
            size = 8,
            color = "rgb(255, 102, 102)",
            opacity = 0.4,
            line = dict(
                width=0.5,
                color='rgb(255, 102, 102)'
            )
        ),
        name = state
    )
    cities.append(city)

cities_year = []
for year in sorted(data.year.value_counts().index):
    data_sub = data.loc[data['year'] == year]
    city = dict(
        type = 'scattergeo',
        visible = False,
        locationmode = 'USA-states',
        lon = data_sub['lon'],
        lat = data_sub['lat'],
        mode = 'markers',
        marker = dict(
            size = 8,
            color = "rgb(255, 102, 102)",
            opacity = 0.4,
            line = dict(
                width=0.5,
                color='rgb(255, 102, 102)'
            )
        ),
        name = str(year)
    )
    cities_year.append(city)

slider = [dict(active = 0,
               pad = dict(t = 1),
               steps = [dict(args = ["visible", ([False] * len(cities)) + [True, False, False, False]], 
                             label = "1990",
                             method = "restyle"
                            ),
                        dict(args = ["visible", ([False] * len(cities)) + [False, True, False, False]],
                             label = "1991", 
                             method = "restyle"
                            ),
                        dict(args = ["visible", ([False] * len(cities)) + [False, False, True, False]],
                             label = "1992",
                             method = "restyle"
                            ),
                        dict(args = ["visible", ([False] * len(cities)) + [False, False, False, True]],
                             label = "1993",
                             method = "restyle"
                            )
                       ]
              )
         ]

updatemenus = list([
    dict(type="buttons",
         active=0,
         buttons=list([   
            dict(label = 'states',
                 method = 'update',
                 args = [dict(visible = ([True] * len(cities)) + ([False] * len(cities_year))),
                         dict(sliders = [],
                              showlegend = True)]),
            dict(label = 'years',
                 method = 'update',
                 args = [dict(visible = ([False] * len(cities)) + [True, False, False, False]),
                         dict(sliders = slider,
                              showlegend = False)])
        ]),
     )
])

layout = dict(
    title = 'myplot',
    geo = dict(
        scope='usa',
        projection=dict(type='albers usa'),
        showland=True,
        showlakes = True,
        landcolor = 'rgb(217, 217, 217)',
        subunitwidth=1,
        countrywidth=1,
        subunitcolor="rgb(255, 255, 255)",
        countrycolor="rgb(255, 255, 255)"
    ),
    updatemenus=updatemenus
)

trace_data = cities + cities_year
fig = dict(data=trace_data, layout=layout)
iplot(fig, validate=False)
```

Comment: Can you add some data to have a [MCVE]?

Comment: I added some code that create a fake dataset @MaximilianPeters

Answer (score 0):

Problem: If I understand correctly, when the above `code` is run: The `iplot()` creates the `scattergeo()` plot with two [buttons](https://plot.ly/python/custom-buttons/) labeled '`states`' and '`years`'. Of these two buttons namely the '`states`' button is active and showing its plot (with 'red dots' and `legend`). The '`years`' button corresponds to a plot with a `slider` option (`years` `1990` to `1993`). Now, when this '`years`' button is clicked the expectation is that the 'red dots' should appear across the `maps` (for `year` `1990`). However, this does not happen.

**Plot when above code is run**
[image: Plot when above code is run]

**Problem plot with no data points when 'years' button is clicked**
[image]

**Attempted solution:**

When `visible` is set to `True` (below) in `city` `dictionary` for `cities_year` `list` of `traces`, then the problem is solved. That is after the `code` is run the plot appears with two buttons. Now when the '`years`' `button` is `clicked`, it shows the 'red dots' for the with `slider` at the `year` `1990`. Setting `visible=True` may be important because it could be for the very first instance when the `plot` is loaded or displayed. (`Jupyter Notebook 5.0.0`; `Python 3.6.6`)

```
cities_year = []
for year in sorted(data.year.value_counts().index):
    data_sub = data.loc[data['year'] == year]
    city = dict(
        type = 'scattergeo',
        visible = True,
```

Plot after `code` is run:
[image]

Now when the 'years' button is clicked the plot is:
[image]

**Edit - 1** - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

The `slider` still does not work as expected. However found a work around using just the `legends` for selection of `year`.

```
    dict(label = 'years',
         method = 'restyle',
         args = [dict(visible = ([False] * len(cities)) + [True, True, True, True]),
                 dict(sliders = slider,
                      showlegend = False)])
```

[image]

**Edit - 2** - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

Issue is still unresolved, but code below may help narrow down finding the bug. In the `code` below, there are two sample data sets for: (1) `go.Scatter()` and (2) `go.Scattergeo()`. There are only `5` `rows` in total in each `dataframe` to keep it simple. Note that although the `code` for generating the sample data set is different, following the code works to plot both of the above data sets. It shows that the `go.Scatter()` works fine, and `go.Scattergeo()` has the issue mentioned in the question.

**Import libraries**

```
import datetime
from datetime import date
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from plotly import __version__
%matplotlib inline

import cufflinks as cf
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot 
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
cf.go_offline()

import plotly.offline as pyo
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.tools import FigureFactory as FF

import json
```

**Create data for `go.Scatter()`**

```
# Create random numbers
x = np.random.randn(100)
y = 10 + np.random.randn(100)
z = np.linspace(-3,2,100)
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':x, 'y':y, 'z':z})
df.head(2)

# Create traces
trace1 = go.Scatter(visible = True, x=df.x, y=df.y, mode='markers', name='trace1', marker=dict(color='red'))
trace2 = go.Scatter(visible = True, x=df.x, y=df.z, mode='markers', name='trace2', marker=dict(color='black'))

trace3 = go.Scatter(visible = False, x=df.x, y=df.y*df.y, mode='markers', name='trace3', marker=dict(color='blue'))
trace4 = go.Scatter(visible = False, x=df.x, y=df.z*0.5, mode='markers', name='trace4', marker=dict(color='orange'))
trace5 = go.Scatter(visible = False, x=df.x, y=df.z*df.z, mode='markers', name='trace5', marker=dict(color='purple'))

# Create list of traces 
data = [trace1, trace2, trace3, trace4, trace5]
```

**Create data for `go.Scattergeo()`**

```
# Create dataframe for cities
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['New York', 'Los Angeles', 'Chicago', 'Houston', 'Philadelphia'],
                  'pop': [8287238, 3826423, 2705627, 2129784, 1539313],
                  'lat': [40.730599, 34.053717, 41.875555, 29.758938, 39.952335],
                  'lon': [-73.986581, -118.242727, -87.624421, -95.367697, -75.163789],
                   'year': [1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1991]
                })


# Create city traces manually without for-loop
trace1 = go.Scattergeo(visible=True,name = 'trace1',locationmode = 'USA-states',
                   lon = df[df['name']=='New York']['lon'], lat = df[df['name']=='New York']['lat'], 
                   mode = 'markers',marker = dict(size=10, symbol='circle-open', color = "red")) 
trace2 = go.Scattergeo(visible=True,name = 'trace2',locationmode = 'USA-states',
                   lon = df[df['name']=='Los Angeles']['lon'], lat = df[df['name']=='Los Angeles']['lat'], 
                   mode = 'markers',marker = dict(size=10, symbol='circle-open', color = "red")) 


trace3 = go.Scattergeo(visible=False, name = 'trace3', locationmode = 'USA-states',
                   lon = df[df['year']==1990]['lon'], lat = df[df['year']==1990]['lat'],
                   mode = 'markers',marker = dict(size=20, symbol='circle-open', color = "blue")
                  ) 
trace4 = go.Scattergeo(visible=False, name = 'trace4', locationmode = 'USA-states',
                   lon = df[df['year']==1991]['lon'], lat = df[df['year']==1991]['lat'],
                   mode = 'markers',marker = dict(size=20, symbol='circle-open', color = "blue")
                  )  
trace5 = go.Scattergeo(visible=False, name = 'trace5', locationmode = 'USA-states',
                   lon = df[df['year']==1992]['lon'], lat = df[df['year']==1992]['lat'],
                   mode = 'markers',marker = dict(size=20, symbol='circle-open', color = "blue")
                  ) 

# Create list of traces
data = [trace1, trace2, trace3, trace4, trace5]
```

**`Code` below is common to above two data sets**

```
# Create slider
sliders = [dict(active=-1,
               pad = {"t": 1},
               currentvalue = {"prefix": "Plot Number: "},
               execute=True, 
               steps = [
                        dict(args = ["visible", [False, False, True, False, False]],
                             label = "trace3", 
                             method = "restyle"
                            ),
                        dict(args = ["visible", [False, False, False,True, False]],
                             label = "trace4",
                             method = "restyle"
                            ),
                        dict(args = ["visible", [False, False, False, False, True]],
                             label = "trace5",
                             method = "restyle"
                            )
                       ],
                transition = 0
              )
         ]

# Create updatemenus
updatemenus = list([
    dict(
        buttons= list([
                        dict(
                             args = [
                                    {'visible': (True, False, False, False, False)},
                                    {'sliders':[], 'showlegend': True, 'title': 'Plots only'}
                                    ],
                             label = 'single_plot',
                             method = 'update'

                    ),
                         dict(
                             args = [
                                    {'visible': (False, False, True, False, False)},
                                    {'sliders':sliders, 'showlegend': True, 'title': 'Plots with slider'}
                                    ],
                             label = 'multi_plots',
                             method = 'update'

                    )
        ]),
        direction = 'left',
        pad = {'r': 10, 't': 10},
        showactive = True,
        type = 'buttons',
        x = 0.1,
        xanchor = 'left',
        y = 1,
        yanchor = 'top' 
    )])

# Create layout
layout = go.Layout(title='Chart') #, geo=dict(scope='usa')) #<--uncomment for Scattergeo() ... optional
layout['updatemenus'] = updatemenus

# Plot data
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
pyo.offline.plot(fig)
```

**Plots with `go.Scatter()`**

*(Left: Plot for `button` '`single_plot`'; Right: plot for `button` '`multi_plots`')*

Note, here the plot on the right-side data points show correctly after pressing 'multi_points' `button`.

[image]

**Plots with `go.Scattergeo()`**

*(Left: Plot for `button` '`single_plot`'; Right: plot for `button` '`multi_plots`')*

Note, here the data points are missing in the plot on the right-side after pressing '`multi_points`' button.

[image]

Comment: I tried what you said but doing this plots every point twice. If you set the color of `marker` dict to something like `color = "rgb(113, 8, 80)"` inside of `cities_year` dict then you can see the two colors on the initial plot where `states` button is active

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I understand the issue now. I've updated the previous post with a workaround. However still could not figure out how to get the `slider` to show-up. Probably missing somthing in the `call` to `updatemenus`. I'll update the post if I am able to find a solution to the slider.

Comment: I tried another approach. The `Edit-2` shows that `code` that runs two different `data` set's of `traces` through the same `code` to create different `plots`. It seems to an issue specific to `go.Scattergeo()`. Not sure if its a `bug` or the way its implemented. I search through the `plotly` documentation but could not find what `parameter` would made it do that. The `go.Scatter()` seems to work just fine.